# If $P$ is a regular transition probability matrix then $P^{n^2}$ has no zero element

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

A transition probability matrix $P\in M_{n\times n}$ is regular if for some $k$ the matrix $P^k$ has all of its elements strictly positive. I read that this can be tested by using the following result.

If $P$ is a regular transition probability matrix then $P^{n^2}$ has no zero element.

But how does one prove this? And is it true that for each $1\le i< n^2$ one can find $P$ regular where $P^i$ has at least one zero entry.

Comment: You are probably interested in the converse implication (this one being a trivial consequence of the definition).

Comment: @Did Oh yah I had that backwards. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Edited out a typo --- thanks, Ilya]

EDIT: Theorem. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with nonnegative entries, and some power of $A$ has only positive entries, then $A^q$ has only positive entries, where $q=n^2-2n+2$. This is sharp; there is a matrix for which $A^{q-1}$ does not have only positive entries.

The Theorem is due to Wielandt. A nice discussion appears in Hans Schneider, Wielandt's [proof](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~schneidh/wielproof2.pdf) of the exponent inequality for primitive nonnegative matrices, Linear Algebra and its Applications 353 (2002) 5-10. Schneider also refers to Section 3.5 of Brualdi and Ryser, Combinatorial Matrix Theory.

See also page 11 of this [webpage](http://www.hamilton.ie/ollie/Downloads/Pos1.pdf). Also Holladay and Varga, On [powers](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1958-009-04/S0002-9939-1958-0097416-8/S0002-9939-1958-0097416-8.pdf) of non-negative matrices, Proc AMS (1958) 631-634.

MORE EDIT. The smallest exponent $r$ such that $A^r$ has only positive entries has been denoted $\gamma(A)$ in the literature; it is sometimes called the *exponent* of $A$, sometimes, the *index of primitivity*. By Wielandt, $$\gamma(A)\le n^2-2n+2$$ So the question arises, given $n$, for which $m$ with $1\le m\le n^2-2n+2$ is there an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with $\gamma(A)=m$?

The question is answered in

1. Lewin and Vitek, A system of gaps in the exponent set of primitive matrices, Illinois J Math 25 (1981) 87-98, MR 82h:15026
2. Jia Yu Shao, On a conjecture about the exponent set of primitive matrices, Lin Alg Appl 65 (1985) 91-123, MR 86k:15013
3. Ke Min Zhang, On Lewin and Vitek's conjecture about the exponent set of primitive matrices, Lin Alg Appl 96 (1987) 101-108, MR 88j:15019.

Lewin and Vitek showed that given arbitrary integers $n$ and $t$ there is no $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with $$n^2-tn+(t+1)^2/4\lt\gamma(A)\lt n^2-(t-1)n+t-2$$ (the cases $t=3$ and $t=4$ go back to a 1964 paper of Dulmage and Mendelsohn). They further conjectured that there are no gaps in the exponent set below $1+(n^2-2n+2)/2$.

Shao went some way toward establishing the Lewin-Vitek conjecture but also showed it was false for $n=11$.

Zhang then proved that $n=11$ is the only exception to the Lewin-Vitek conjecture.

[What follows is wrong stuff from an earlier edit, retained here for historical reasons. Please ignore.

[If $P^k$ has the same number of zeros as $P^{k+1}$, then $P^r$ has that many zeros for all $r\ge k$. So in order for $P$ to be regular, each power of $P$ must have at least one zero fewer than the previous power. Since $P$ can't have more than $n^2$ zeros....

[I think $n^2$ can be sharpened to $n(n-1)/2$, though I'm not prepared to give a proof or a reference. I don't know whether one can achieve every value between $1$ and $n(n-1)/2$.]

Comment: Did you mean $k$ in place of $m?$

Comment: You might want to add a reason why "If $P^k$ has the same number of zeros as $P^{k+1}$, then $P^r$ has that many zeros for all $r\ge k$".

Comment: @Did, I thought that was obvious, but now that you mention it, it could be a bit tricky. Anyway, Wielandt's $n^2-2n+2$ is better than my implied $n^2$, so maybe I should just delete everything before the EDIT?

Comment: Well, a reason why the number of zeroes should be decreasing is not clear (if it is true).