# $A$ is a Regular Transition Matrix $\Rightarrow$ $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} A^m$ exists and rank 1

Tags: transition-matrix

A is  a Regular Transition Matrix  $\Rightarrow$ $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} A^m$ exists and rank 1

At the above proposition, what does "regular" mean?

Answer (score 0):

> Def: $A$ is regular if some power of $A$ has all positive entries.

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376828/when-to-stop-checking-if-a-transition-matrix-is-regular) and [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~daddel/linear_algebra_appl/Applications/MarkovChain/MarkovChain_9_18/node2.html).

This comes up for regular Markov chains (i.e. Markov chains with a regular transition matrix).

Concerning the statement you reference:
$$
A \;\,\text{regular} \;\;\implies\;\;  \text{rank}\left(\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} A^m\right)=1
$$
this is because any *regular* transition matrix $A$ satisfies
$$
S:=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} A^m =
\begin{bmatrix}
s_1 & s_1 & \ldots & s_1 \\
s_2 & s_2 & \ldots & s_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\ 
s_n & s_n & \ldots & s_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $s = (s_1, \ldots, s_n)$ is the *steady state* distribution of the Markov chain (with $||s||_1=1$).

Notice that the rank of $S$ is obviously 1, because there is only one linearly independent column. Intuitively, this means a regular Markov chain converges to a distribution $s$ after sufficient time passes, no matter what its initial distribution was and that this does not change as time passes further (i.e. $As=s$).