Test Whether a Markov Matrix is Irreducible
Given a finite-state discrete time homogeneous Markov chain with N states and transition matrix $P$, a test for irreducibility is to determine whether this sum $$I + P + P^{2} + ... + P^{N-1} > 0$$ for all $(i,j)$ elements in that sum.
Does anyone have a reference for this test?

Welcome to MSE! Are you saying that this must be true for some $N$ or for all $N$? For the latter, notice that all the entries of $P$ are positive, what can you say about the entries of the sum $I+P+\dots+P^N$?

Thank you for the welcome; for all N

Note it goes only up to N-1

If all the (i,j) entries in the matrix that is the above sum are all positive then the Markov transition matrix P is irreducible.

For $N=1$, it would mean that all the entries of the identity matrix are non zero, which is clearly false... we can prove that the Markov chain is irreducible if and only if it is true for some $N$. Note that it doesn't matter to go up to $N$ or to $N-1$.

In an N=2-state Markov chain, the above sum is I + P. The sum is from 0 to N-1. Assume the minimum is always a 2-state MC. So, I'm still looking for a reference for this in the literature.

There's a theorem of Wielandt, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450090/if-p-is-a-regular-transition-probability-matrix-then-pn2-has-no-zero-ele

Sorry for the confusion. I didn't find any reference for this result, but the proof seems accessible: all the entries of $P$ being $>0$, $(I+\dots+P^{N-1}){i,j}>0$ for all $(i,j)$ is equivalent to "for all $(i,j)$ there exists $k<N$ such that $P{i,j}^k>0$". So you would need to show that if a (nonzero probability) path exists between $i$ and $j$, then there exists one with length $<N$. Suppose for some $(i,j)$, the smallest's length was greater than $N$, such a path would visit some state twice and we would be able to find an even smaller one, and this would raise a contradiction.

yes, indeed ... very nice Kolakoski54
